# Polynomial regression equation

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I am trying to correlate two sediment cores as I have different samples at varying depths within the cores. I have used the ggplot 2 function to plot a 5th order polynomial regression, displaying the equation and r2 value on the graph.

The issue I am having is with the equation itself, the r2 value is correct but the equation is not. I think this is to do with lm_eq referring to linear regression but I am not too sure.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I am happy with the graph itself but any suggestions on how to clean up my code would also be greatly appreciated.

I have tried googling other functions on how to show the equation but have not found a solution.

```
long_data <- gather(Correlations, key = "Core", value = "Depth",
#Reshapes my data frame
                    LC1U, LC3U) 
df <- data.frame("x"=long_data$Sample, "y"=long_data$Depth)

lm_eqn = function(df){   m=lm(y ~ poly(x, 5), df)#3rd degree polynomial   eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2,
                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2),
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 4)))   as.character(as.expression(eq)) }

p1 <- ggplot(long_data, aes(x=Sample,y=Depth)) + geom_point(aes(color=Core)) +  
    labs(x ='Sample N.', y ='Depth (mm)', title = 'Core Correlation of Lake Nganoke') +  
    ylim(1,800) 

p1 + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~poly(x,5, raw = TRUE), size = 1) +    
    annotate("text", x = 0, y = 800, label = lm_eqn(df), hjust=0, family="Times", parse = TRUE) + #Add polynomial regression
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = c(0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800))
```

[image: My graph]

Comment: Not sure why you have been down voted as a first poster. You do seem to have done some homework and new to posting culture of SO. Unfortunately, while new myself to GGPLOT, can not offer you a solution.  Hope someone can. If you find a solution do post the answer to your question.

Comment: Try setting `raw` to TRUE. `lm(y ~ poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE), data = df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `lm_eqn` is tailored to show the equation of a linear regression, i.e. the polynomial of the first degree. I've modified it to show the equation of a polynomial of the Nth degree. Since you haven't posted your data (sth you should do in the future and prob why your question was initially down voted), I've used the `cars` data set from `datasets`.

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

lm_eqn <- function(df, degree, raw=TRUE){
  m <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree, raw=raw), df)  # get the fit
  cf <- round(coef(m), 2)  # round the coefficients
  r2 <- round(summary(m)$r.squared, 4)  # round the r.squared
  powers <- paste0("^", seq(length(cf)-1))  # create the powers for the equation
  powers[1] <- ""  # remove the first one as it's redundant (x^1 = x)
  # first check the sign of the coefficient and assign +/- and paste it with
  # the appropriate *italic(x)^power. collapse the list into a string
  pcf <- paste0(ifelse(sign(cf[-1])==1, " + ", " - "), abs(cf[-1]),
                paste0("*italic(x)", powers), collapse = "")
  # paste the rest of the equation together
  eq <- paste0("italic(y) == ", cf[1], pcf, "*','", "~italic(r)^2==", r2)
  eq
}

df <- data.frame("x" = cars$speed, "y" = cars$dist)
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE), size = 1) +    
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 100, label = lm_eqn(df, 5, raw = TRUE),
           hjust = 0, family = "Times", parse = TRUE)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative answer. I observed that the endpoints of the polynomial in your plot exhibit curvature that does not apper to follow the shape of the data (Runge's phenomenon) so I extracted the data from your scatterplot and made an equation search. The best candidate I can find appears to be "y = C/(1.0 + exp((x-A)/B)) + D * exp((x-B)/E)" as shown below with the Y axis plotted in the normal fashion. For the parameters

```
A =  4.1190742945259711E+00
B = -6.4849391432073888E-01
C =  3.5527347656282654E+02
D =  1.7759549500121045E+02
E =  2.1295437650578787E+01
```

I obtain  R-squared = 0.9604 and RMSE = 36.37 and note the plotted extremes of the equation do not exhibit the curvature shown for the polynomial. If this might be useful, you would need to re-fit using the actual study data with these parameter values as the initial parameter estimates for the non-linear solver.

[image: plot]

Comment: You are right, the data was a mock dataset I had created roughly. I should have stated that I did not expect it to follow a polynomial trend from the start.

Comment: No problem. Any time I get to use the phrase "Runge's phenomenon" it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Arienhood for the help! It turned out that my data in this sequence didn't follow a polynomial trend however further use of this code will. (Will definitely post my dataset in the future)

```
library(ggplot2)

lm_eqn <- function(df, degree, raw=TRUE){
  m <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree, raw=raw), df)  
  cf <- round(coef(m), 2)  
  r2 <- round(summary(m)$r.squared, 4)  
  powers <- paste0("^", seq(length(cf)-1))  
  powers[1] <- ""  

  pcf <- paste0(ifelse(sign(cf[-1])==1, " + ", " - "), abs(cf[-1]),
                paste0("*italic(x)", powers), collapse = "")

  eq <- paste0("italic(y) == ", cf[1], pcf, "*','", "~italic(r)^2==", r2)
  eq
}

df <- data.frame("x"=Correlations$LC3U, "y"=Correlations$LC1U)

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x ='LC3U', y ='LC1U', title = 'Core Correlation of Lake Nganoke') +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 1, raw = TRUE), size = 1) +
  annotate("text", x = 10, y = 10, label = lm_eqn(df, 1, raw = TRUE),
           hjust = 0, family = "Times", parse = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80))

p2
```

[image: Plot]